# how to parse the " log 2017-12-18 00:00:00,098 DEBUG Test - In test class " using grok and logstsh

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I have log of the of the below format. 
2017-12-18 00:00:00,098 DEBUG Test - In test class 
I want stash the log with logstash and grok filter.I am getting the output in following format.

```
 {
          "@version" => "1",
              "host" => "ip-172-30-0-112",
              "path" => "/home/ubuntu/logstash-6.0.0/apl.log",
        "@timestamp" => 2017-12-19T11:32:03.692Z,
           "message" => "2017-12-18 00:00:00,098 DEBUG SdkTLSSocketFactory - Starting handshake",
              "type" => "apache_access"
 }
```

But i want the parsed log that includes in timestamp,loglevel,Class name, name log message.

I am using `%{DATESTAMP:timestamp} %{WORD:level} %{WORD:location} \- %{GREEDYDATA}` to parse the log.

Comment: I don't see what you are trying to do. Perhaps an example of what you want as output would help.

Comment: I am expecting the output that includes below fields . 

{
"@version" => "1",
              "host" => "ip-172-30-0-112",
              "path" => "/home/ubuntu/logstash-6.0.0/apl.log",
               "@timestamp" => 2017-12-19T11:32:03.692Z,
               "message" => "2017-12-18 00:00:00,098 DEBUG SdkTLSSocketFactory - Starting handshake",
               "type" => "apache_access"
                "loglevel" => "DEBUG"
                "classname" => "SdkTLSSocketFactory"
                "logmessage"=> "Starting handshake"
 }

Comment: Update your question instead of putting this in the comments, that's barely legible

Comment: So apparently you don't even know how to add a filter plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Between the `input` and the `output` parts of your configuration, if it's not yet present, add a `filter` block, with the grok filter configured with the pattern you indicated in your question.

```
input{
  ...
}

filter {
  grok {
    match => ["message", "%{DATESTAMP:timestamp} %{WORD:level} %{WORD:location} \- %{GREEDYDATA}"]
  }
}

output{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

pipeline.conf

```
input{
        file{
                path => "/path/to/logfile"
                sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
                start_position => "beginning"
        }
}
filter{
        grok{
                match => {"message" => "%{DATESTAMP:timestamp} %{WORD:logLevel} %{WORD:className} \- %{GREEDYDATA:logMessage}"}
        }
}
output{
        stdout{
                codec => rubydebug
        }
}
```

Sample output ::

```
{
          "path" => "/path/to/logfile",
    "@timestamp" => 2017-12-19T13:37:26.542Z,
      "logLevel" => "DEBUG",
    "logMessage" => "Starting handshake",
      "@version" => "1",
          "host" => "HOST",
     "className" => "SdkTLSSocketFactory",
       "message" => "2017-12-18 00:00:00,098 DEBUG SdkTLSSocketFactory - Starting handshake",
     "timestamp" => "17-12-18 00:00:00,098"
}
```